# Evaluating the inverse laplace transform of $ X(s) = \frac{2\cdot a^4\cdot s}{s^4+4\cdot a^4} $.

Tags: roots, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

I'm preparing myself for the following exam, it's Signals and Systems. And I'm stuck with this example:

$$ X(s) = \frac{2\cdot a^4\cdot s}{s^4+4\cdot a^4} $$
The task is to find the inverse Laplace transform.

I know that I have to do Partial fraction decomposition, but I'm unable to find the roots for $s^4+4\cdot a^4$.
The roots should be :
$$s_1 = (-1-i)a $$
$$s_2 = (-1+i)a$$
$$s_3 = (1-a)a$$
$$s_4 = (1+a)a$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are unable to find the roots which you already know.

Comment: I found them on wolfram alpha but how do we get them thats the question

Comment: Let $ x = s/a$, then $x^4 + 4 =0 \iff x^4 = -4 \iff x = \pm\sqrt{ \pm 2i}$.

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{2 a^4 s}{4 a^4+s^4}\right](t)=a^2 \sin (a t) \sinh (a t)$$

Comment: I get that also, but I need these, somehow when I'm trying my real part of complex root always disappears.. so its in your  case as well, but thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:)**
\begin{align}
s^4+4a^4
&=s^4+4a^4+4a^2s^2-4a^2s^2 \\
&=(s^2+2a^2)^2-4a^2s^2 \\
&=(s^2-2sa+2a^2)(s^2+2sa+2a^2)\\
&=((s-a)^2+a^2)((s+a)^2+a^2)
\end{align}

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you so much, nice trick by the way!

Comment: @ДавидПрибић Good luck!